# IANA image format string from binary stream

Tags: file-format, images

How can I get the official [IANA Image Media Type](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/image/index.html) (if any) of a binary stream? I'd like to avoid trusting to file extensions and vague guesses when handling images. Preferably some command using common tools like ImageMagick's `identify`, or some programming language if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`file`](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/) command. It's available on most linux distributions by default, and you can get it for Windows via  the [GnuWin32 file package](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm).

Call it with:

```
$ file --mime-type clock.png 
clock.png: image/png
```

Note that it's not 100% accurate - I don't think anything can be theoretically.

If you want to do that in code, there's `libmagic` that provides a [C api](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libmagic). It can process either files or in-memory buffers. (`file` uses that on Linux.)